# React useState hook performance on big objects

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm new to React and I am creating an application where I am using a quite big state with frequent updates. Using `useState()` I understand it will replace the whole object on every update. If that means it will make a full copy of the object, there will be a severe performance hit in m case. If it is some lazy evaluation, I think I might be fine, hence my question.

Contrary, if I would use the old class based `setState()` method, I could update only the necessary parts of the state. For instance, my data structure looks something like this:

```
{
    'data0': { ... some not very deep object ...},
    'data1': { ... },
    'data2': { ... },
    ...,
    'dataN': { ... },
}
```

where I can potentially have thousands of `data` objects. As the `data` objects are quite small, replacing them when needed is not that much of a performance hit, which is perfectly doable with `setState()` in a class, but how is this going to work if using the `useState()` hook?

Answer (score 0):

U can spread previous state with usestate and u will get same result as setstate

```
Usestate([
 ...state,
    Data6
])
```

Comment: I understand that will give me the same result, but will it be as efficient? Does the `...state` practise some lazy evaluation technique rather than copy all data in the object? Oh, and I'm using it on an object, not an array, if that matters.